# Why does this 'Node' object not have the attribute 'daughters'?

Tags: python

These are my `Graph` and `Node` classes:

```
import random

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.node_list = {}
        self.number = 0

    def node(self, node_name):
        if node_name in self.node_list: #returns list of keys
            return self.node_list[node_name]
        else:
            self.node_list[node_name] = Node()

    def name_node(self):
        if names == False:
            names == []
        if len(names) < 2: 
            for count in range(2 - len(names)):
                names.append('node_' + str(number))
                number += 1
        if names[0] in node_list:
            del names[0]
            return name_node()
        return names.pop(0)
        ...
    class Node:
        def __init__(self):
            daughters = []
            ...

def PrefixTrieConstruction(patterns):
    trie = Graph()
    trie.node('root')

    for pattern in patterns:
        currentNode = trie.node('root')
        for symbol in pattern:
            for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
                if daughter.label == symbol:
                    currentNode = daughter
                    break
            else:
                node_name = Trie.name_node()
                Trie.node(node_name)
                Trie.edge(currentNode, node_name, symbol)
                currentNode = node_name
    return Trie
```

When I run this, it returns an error in reference to the line

```
            for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
```

that

```
Node object has no attribute 'daughters'
```

I put this in the `init`, so every node must have `daughters = []`, I believe.
I also tried adding in a line beneath the `Graph.node` method else clause saying explicitly to return that newly created node.

Why does this attribute not exist?

Answer (score 2):

In `Node.__init__`, you set a local variable `daughters`, not an attribute `self.daughters`.